# What is the name of the song in episode 9 starting around 10:37?

Tags: music, parasyte

I have been looking for the song which plays at around 10:37 in episode 9 of Parasyte the Maxim. I couldn't find it in the OST.

Here's the episode I am talking about [on Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/parasyte-the-maxim-/episode-9-beyond-good-and-evil-662599).

Comment: The link you posted lead to an illegal anime streaming site as such i have removed it. please refer to [this answer](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587) ti find a legal streaming source

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a playlist someone posted on Reddit with the song I was looking for. https://youtu.be/CdOc3BAOKHo track 4, titled "LIZARD".